# Want to add new column to a pandas dataframe after resampling the api tick data

Tags: pandas, api, resampling, pandas-resample

I have a program that convert api live tick data to a 15 Sec time Dataframe. But in the new dataframe some old columns are missing which is very much necessary from my further work. How can fetch those old columns to my new dataframe. I want to add ts, tk ...which are very important for me.

```
def df_tech(df, interval):
    df = df[['ts','tk','lp', 'pc', 'ltq']]
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['ft'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df1 = df['lp'].resample(interval).ohlc().bfill()
    df1['ShortEMA'] = df1.close.ewm(span=10, adjust=False).mean()
    df1['LongEMA']  = df1.close.ewm(span=21, adjust=False).mean()
    return df1
```

Comment: can you share the code where u r fetching the data from api

Comment: I am getting this data from finvasia api

Comment: can you post the data that you directly are getting from the API, and then the code where u r processing it

Comment: sent you message in your fb messenger

Comment: fb messeneger, how did you get my id?

Comment: check message at request and then spam

Comment: nope don't see it, mail me(check my profile)

Comment: mail sent as well as my fb id......try to connect me there.